# In Gnomoria, why is my inventory empty for the Send Tribute menu?

Tags: gnomoria

When I attempt to send tribute, my inventory for sending it seems to be empty, but I have lots of resources that Im able to trade with merchants. Are there more specific items needed for sending tribute?